# How to deploy tuleap alm in openshift?

Tags: openshift, alm

Need to deploy Tuleap ALM in Openshift. Any one please help. I don't know which cartridge to use and how to do. I know deploying java ear or war or files onto openshift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no cartige for Tuleap on OpenShift yet.